# Psyllium husk as gelatin replacement.

Tags: gelatin, marshmallow

Does anyone have experience using psyllium husk in place of gelatin. (My particular situation is making marshmallows)

Comment: Why would you use psyllum? It doesn't sound like a good choice, will give you a very unusual texture.

Comment: @rumtscho I am trying to make vegan and starch free marshmallows. So I tried and it sort of worked. Wouldn't really fluff up enough.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it worked better than my pessimistic expectation of it let me believe. Also, I think the info on your goals is important for those who want to answer, so it is good you shared that.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use psyllium husk. It tastes terrible and no amount of sugar will mask the taste.

Try using agar-agar instead, that's what vegans use for vegan marshmallows.

In Asia, they sometimes use konjac for it, but you will have to be very careful eating it because people die from accidental choking.

Answer (score -1):

I do not have much experience of using it but perhaps I read in some place that Agar or Corn starch is used as a substitute of gelatine.